# How to redirect user outside of react but on the same domain?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony, react-router, symfony4

My app is built with react and Symfony 4.

I use Symfony 4 for all the backend as well as all the public parts of the site for SEO purposes (blog/landing page/legals and so on).

Now I would like to redirect my user from my react app to my webapp (after he/she logs out).
For example, I would like `my-app.com/logout` to be on a Symfony webpage and NOT on my react app. So from `my-app.com/dashboard`, if I click logout (or landing page or blog) I go to `my-app.com/logout` (or landingpage or blog).

How would I do that? A friend told me I should create a sub domaine. Is there any other way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can simply redirect from react app. Why not?

Answer (score 4):

If redirecting outside react app, why don't you use `window.location.href`? Try it out.

Comment: Yeah, whenever the route matches "outside" the app, you set `window.location.href` and hard reload the page. Which the server should know in that URL to serve the other HTML page and not the React HTML.

Comment: thanks guys, I thought that would have been too easy to be true! Ok will try and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would let [Symfony handle all the routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-annotations).

We have a similar setup, React App and Symfony Backend and our git repository has the following structure:

```
--
  -- frontend
  -- symfony
```

where frontend contains all the React stuff.

We only deploy the symfony part to our Webserver (via Jenkins) and during the build the index.html and assets are copied to the symfony folder. So our package.json looks something like this:

```
"scripts": {
...
  "build": "npm run build && cp build/index.html ../symfony/templates/index/index.html.twig && cp -R build/static/ && cp -R build/static/* ../symfony/public/static/",
},
"homepage": "/static/",
```

So for /dashboard or /index or just / -> serve your react stuff and for the additional pages/routes like /logout or /blog create seperate routes, controllers and templates.

Comment: thank you @Chris, I'm working on serving react for the platform atm. Do you know any good doc to redirect from S4 to React the proper way?

Comment: @MilesM. What is "the platform atm"? I'm afraid, I still do not fully understand, what you mean with "redirect".

Comment: Hey Chris thank you for your answer and my apologizes for the poor english syntax. My question was: I'm trying to set up a platform that serves both symfony/php backend and React. I am looking for good documentation that explains how to do this (doesn't have to be with symfony). So far all I found is SO questions and answers. Thank you very much.